# office-ui-fabric-react upload file compoment and country-region-selector abscent

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

how can get the "upload file" and "country-region-selector" compoments in office-ui-fabric-react.
it seems that office Ui fabric doesnot have those compoments.

on React there is only this https://npm.runkit.com/react-file-input for the "upload file"
and this [enter link description here](https://github.com/benkeen/react-country-region-selector) for the "country-region-selector"

but not with css of office UI fabric ?

any idea how to adapt those react native compoments to Office UI fabric or is there any compoments on Office-UI-Fabric, 
and how can we explore the file with adding it to list.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing implementation for country region based on [official link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/dropdown),while you could custom [React-Country-Region-Selector](https://github.com/benkeen/react-country-region-selector) style by classes/IDs properties.

Sample code:

[image]

[image]

The upload control which i used is [material ui Raised Button](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button)(i'm not professional for material ui, but you may try it)

Update:

If you're using latest `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint` and use React as the framework for your SPFx webpart, you could import the Office UI Fabric component directly and use it. for example:

```
import {
  Dropdown,
  Button
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib'

...
<Dropdown
                className='Dropdown-example'
                label='Disabled uncontrolled example with defaultSelectedKey:'
                defaultSelectedKey='D'
                options={
                  [
                    { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
                    { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
                    { key: 'C', text: 'Option c' },
                    { key: 'D', text: 'Option d' },
                    { key: 'E', text: 'Option e' },
                    { key: 'F', text: 'Option f' },
                    { key: 'G', text: 'Option g' },
                  ]
                }                
                disabled={ false }
              />
```

[image]

Comment: thank you n the function it works but not on ui fabric display : https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Dropdown/Dropdown.html there"s an error on var Dropdown = new fabric['Dropdown'](DropdownHTMLElements[i]);  : error =Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Dropdown is not a constructor

Comment: Check my update and the official sample https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components